# Python: for-loop + break versus while + flag performances

Tags: python, performance

Our programming teacher recommends using a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop if we want to use a `return` statement in the loop, on the premise that "Python optimizes the `for` loop by unrolling it when you give it a table, so if you put a `return` in the middle it will waste memory and time".

I've worked with Python for several years now, and I can say for sure based on the Python specs that this is false (loop unrolling is only done by CPython if the body of the loop is "simple").

Basically he's saying that this code:

```py
def check_five(tab):
    for elem in tab:
        if elem > 5:
            return True
    return False
```

Will cause performance issues and should be replaced by

```
def check_five(tab):
    i = 0
    found = False
    while i < len(tab) and not found:
        if tab[i] > 5:
            found = True
        i += 1
    return found
```

which is both less pythonic and more bloated.

I've done some benchmarks, the `while` one is about 3 times slower than the `for` one takes.

Is there any truth in his reasoning? (Is there any edge case where it would be true?)

**Note:** This is **not** a question about when to use a `for` loop or a `while` loop, this is a question about the performance of both. I am also aware of better ways to write this using `any()`, but sadly we're only allowed to use stuff we've already covered in class. Also we're on Python 3.

Comment: show him your timings and discuss it with your teacher? maybe he is on python 2.5 still?  timings are evidence against his "believe"

Comment: I would not use either: use `return any(x>5 for x in tab)` - wich is even more pythonic

Comment: CPython never unrolls anything. And even if, it is never waste of time.

Comment: @PatrickArtner, Purely in terms of performance I expect `any` + a generator expression to be *less* efficient.. iterating a generator is expensive relative to a simple `for` loop. Yes, the generator expression is idiomatic, but not recommended for large generators *where performance is an issue*.

Comment: If nothing else the while loop has 4 extra steps (Calculate length of `tab`, compare `i` to length, test `found`, increment `i`).

Comment: Under no circumstances that while loop can be faster than the for loop, primarily because it does not short-circuit so it **always** have to iterate over the entire list/whatever `tab` is + do all the extra stuff it is doing.

Comment: @jpp less efficient ... probably. But _Beautiful is better than ugly._ and _Explicit is better than implicit._ and _Simple is better than complex._ ... and if that task is "performance-critical" you are better off using the for loop - but until I get a bottleneck I would rather use `any()` 99 times out of 100

Comment: @PatrickArtner You are generally correct, but the entire premise of this question is performance

Comment: @DeepSpace note that here it does short-circuit since it checks that `found` is `False`

Comment: @zdimension You are correct, I missed that. However the `for` loop is still much more efficient

Answer (score 2):

Just show your teacher this output of `dis` (no pun intended).

```
from dis import dis

def for_check_five(tab):
    for elem in tab:
        if elem > 5:
            return True
    return False


def while_check_five(tab):
    i = 0
    found = False
    while i < len(tab) and not found:
        if tab[i] > 5:
            found = True
        i += 1
    return found


dis(for_check_five)
print()
print('--------------')
print()
dis(while_check_five)
```

Output

```
104           0 SETUP_LOOP              24 (to 26)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (tab)
              4 GET_ITER
        >>    6 FOR_ITER                16 (to 24)
              8 STORE_FAST               1 (elem)

105          10 LOAD_FAST                1 (elem)
             12 LOAD_CONST               1 (5)
             14 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
             16 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        6

106          18 LOAD_CONST               2 (True)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
             22 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            6
        >>   24 POP_BLOCK

107     >>   26 LOAD_CONST               3 (False)
             28 RETURN_VALUE

--------------

111           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              2 STORE_FAST               1 (i)

112           4 LOAD_CONST               2 (False)
              6 STORE_FAST               2 (found)

113           8 SETUP_LOOP              44 (to 54)
        >>   10 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             12 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (len)
             14 LOAD_FAST                0 (tab)
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             18 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             20 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       52
             22 LOAD_FAST                2 (found)
             24 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        52

114          26 LOAD_FAST                0 (tab)
             28 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             30 BINARY_SUBSCR
             32 LOAD_CONST               3 (5)
             34 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
             36 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       42

115          38 LOAD_CONST               4 (True)
             40 STORE_FAST               2 (found)

116     >>   42 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             44 LOAD_CONST               5 (1)
             46 INPLACE_ADD
             48 STORE_FAST               1 (i)
             50 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           10
        >>   52 POP_BLOCK

117     >>   54 LOAD_FAST                2 (found)
             56 RETURN_VALUE
```

Show your teacher how much more work the `while` loop has to do. That + the profiling data you have should convince you and your teacher who is correct.

Comment: his `while` is suboptimal - mine is better, not sure it is optimal though

Answer (score 0):

Well, this while loop is slower, because more happens: you check two conditions every time you iterate, and inside the while block you index a list, you do the same check as in the for-loop and you add 1 to i. If you want to compare the performance of for and while, it would be better to do the same amount of work in both.

Comment: I don't think the `while` loop does more work since the `__iter__` function of the `range` object also checks for the same condition. So both loops do the same checks

Comment: That would be true if the while depended on one condition, I think. Anyway, the while loop does a lot more, as much more elaborately shown by the reply of @DeepSpace.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer `any(x>5 for x in tab)` .. but to make your while loop faster you can time:

```
def check_five(tab):
    i = 0
    len_tab = len(tab)-1
    while tab[i] <= 5 and i < len_tab:
         i += 1
    return tab[i] > 5
```

This shaves off some operations you do in *your* while loop:

- replacing `len(tab)` by a local variable that holds the value
- removing some variables and conditionals you do not need to use

> ```
> def while_check_five(tab):
>     i = 0
>     found = False                         # dont need this
>     while i < len(tab) and not found:     # dont need len(tab) every loop - if mutable
>         if tab[i] > 5:                    # it might neeed reevaluation in each loop
>             found = True                  # dont need this
>         i += 1
>     return found
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested all answers above. And despite the fact that your while function is not optimized, you're right.

Also, For loop is almost twice faster than using :

```
any(x>5 for x in tab)
```

It seems that the For loop win.

code :

```
import time


def check_five_f(tab):
    """For loop"""
    for elem in tab:
        if elem > 5:
            return True
    return False

def check_five_w(tab):
    """While loop"""
    i = 0
    found = False
    while i < len(tab) and not found:
        if tab[i] > 5:
            found = True
        i += 1
    return found

def check_five_o(tab):
    """Optimized While loop"""
    i = 0
    len_tab = len(tab)-1
    while i < len_tab:
        if tab[i] > 5:
            return True
        i += 1
    return False

def check_five_l(tab):
    return any(x>5 for x in lst)


lst = list(range(-100000000, 10))

# For loop
start = time.time()
check_five_f(lst)
print("For loop : ",time.time() - start, " sec")

#While loop
start = time.time()
check_five_w(lst)
print("While loop : ",time.time() - start, " sec")

# Optimised while loop
start = time.time()
check_five_o(lst)
print("Optimised while loop : ",time.time() - start, " sec")

# List comprehension loop
start = time.time()
check_five_l(test)
print("Using any with List comprehension  : ",time.time() - start, " sec")
```

> Output :
>
> For loop :  3.4106831550598145  sec
>   While loop :  20.234021186828613  sec
>   Optimised while loop :  9.381998538970947  sec
>   List comprehention using any :  6.175985813140869  sec

Comment: This matches the timings I got on my computer. Not sure of the usefulness of the last one since it doesn't do the same thing as the other (it checks if 5 is in the table whereas the others check for the presence of *any value bigger than 5*)